# Do I have to explicitly define a custom _id in a mongoose subdocument?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In mongoose, can I define a subdocument called groups with a custom _id as follows:

All my ids are Strings.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    _id: { type: String },

    firstName: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },
    lastName: { type: String, trim: true, required: true },

    groups: [ {type: String, ref: 'Group'} ]
});
```

or should I have to explicitly code the _id like so:

```
groups: [ { _id: {type: String, ref: 'Group'} } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sub schema, you can tell mongoose object not to generate _id as follow;

```
var group = mobgoose.Schema({
     //fields of group
},{ _id : false });
```

Then you can define _id manually in your controller or anywhere you are using this subschema.